# How to create headless application for Mac OS

Tags: macos

I need to create an application for Mac OS without any visual representation (no views) that should capture key presses and execute AppleScript according to these key presses.

What is the right way to achieve such behavior in Mac OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Launch Daemon, or Launch Agent to run a headless application. You can read about those in [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html).

Comment: So I need to create command line tool project (Swift or Objective-C), copy application to the "/Library/LaunchDaemons" diretory and create .plist file inside it, am I right?

Comment: Sort of! You can also create a Bundle application and use that too, by directing the program string to the binary in the Bundle's Contents/MacOS folder. Note that your application should not be placed in the /Library/LaunchDaemons folder; that's just for the plist

Comment: What is the right place to store my own applications then?

Comment: Depends on the app. I've tried asking this on SO for a daemon application, but didn't get a response. I'm using /usr/local/libexec Take note that if you're planning to distribute via the App Store, this location may not be acceptable.

Comment: Is this still the best solution in 2020?

Comment: @javadba It's the right solution, as designed by Apple.

Comment: Apple also designed `Xcode`. I emphatically avoid it to the extent possible - which is admittedly limited -   by using `AppCode` for all editing and project mgmt.  But in any case - I'll take look. Do you know offhand if this can run in the simulator and/or debugger?

Comment: Oh yea - and I noticed this is in the Documentation _archive_ . In any case I've gone ahead with building a Library which is not the same but mostly meets the needs of developing the backend portion separately from the GUI.